# How to use for/ in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I am new to this I am trying to use a for/in loop with my code.
I have a code that works but I would like it to work in a for/in loop.

This is the source:

```
capitals = ('Kabul', 'Tirana (Tirane)', 'Algiers', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Luanda', "Saint John's", 'Buenos Aires', 'Yerevan', 'Canberra', 'Vienna', 'Baku', 'Nassau', 'Manama', 'Dhaka', 'Bridgetown', 'Minsk', 'Brussels', 'Belmopan', 'Porto Novo', 'Thimphu', 'Sucre', 'Sarajevo', 'Gaborone', 'Brasilia', 'Bandar Seri Begawan', 'Sofia', 'Ouagadougou', 'Gitega', 'Phnom Penh', 'Yaounde', 'Ottawa', 'Praia', 'Bangui', "N'Djamena", 'Santiago', 'Beijing', 'Bogota', 'Moroni', 'Kinshasa', 'Brazzaville', 'San Jose', 'Yamoussoukro', 'Zagreb', 'Havana', 'Nicosia', 'Prague', 'Copenhagen', 'Djibouti', 'Roseau', 'Santo Domingo', 'Dili', 'Quito', 'Cairo', 'San Salvador', 'London', 'Malabo', 'Asmara', 'Tallinn', 'Mbabana', 'Addis Ababa', 'Palikir', 'Suva', 'Helsinki', 'Paris', 'Libreville', 'Banjul', 'Tbilisi', 'Berlin', 'Accra', 'Athens', "Saint George's", 'Guatemala City', 'Conakry', 'Bissau', 'Georgetown', 'Port au Prince', 'Tegucigalpa', 'Budapest', 'Reykjavik', 'New Delhi', 'Jakarta', 'Tehran', 'Baghdad', 'Dublin', 'Jerusalem', 'Rome', 'Kingston', 'Tokyo', 'Amman', 'Nur-Sultan', 'Nairobi', 'Tarawa Atoll', 'Pristina', 'Kuwait City', 'Bishkek', 'Vientiane', 'Riga', 'Beirut', 'Maseru', 'Monrovia', 'Tripoli', 'Vaduz', 'Vilnius', 'Luxembourg', 'Antananarivo', 'Lilongwe', 'Kuala Lumpur', 'Male', 'Bamako', 'Valletta', 'Majuro', 'Nouakchott', 'Port Louis', 'Mexico City', 'Chisinau', 'Monaco', 'Ulaanbaatar', 'Podgorica', 'Rabat', 'Maputo', 'Nay Pyi Taw', 'Windhoek', 'No official capital', 'Kathmandu', 'Amsterdam', 'Wellington', 'Managua', 'Niamey', 'Abuja', 'Pyongyang', 'Skopje', 'Belfast', 'Oslo', 'Muscat', 'Islamabad', 'Melekeok', 'Panama City', 'Port Moresby', 'Asuncion', 'Lima', 'Manila', 'Warsaw', 'Lisbon', 'Doha', 'Bucharest', 'Moscow', 'Kigali', 'Basseterre', 'Castries', 'Kingstown', 'Apia', 'San Marino', 'Sao Tome', 'Riyadh', 'Edinburgh', 'Dakar', 'Belgrade', 'Victoria', 'Freetown', 'Singapore', 'Bratislava', 'Ljubljana', 'Honiara', 'Mogadishu', 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town', 'Seoul', 'Juba', 'Madrid', 'Colombo', 'Khartoum', 'Paramaribo', 'Stockholm', 'Bern', 'Damascus', 'Taipei', 'Dushanbe', 'Dodoma', 'Bangkok', 'Lome', "Nuku'alofa", 'Port of Spain', 'Tunis', 'Ankara', 'Ashgabat', 'Funafuti', 'Kampala', 'Kiev', 'Abu Dhabi', 'London', 'Washington D.C.', 'Montevideo', 'Tashkent', 'Port Vila', 'Vatican City', 'Caracas', 'Hanoi', 'Cardiff', "Sana'a", 'Lusaka', 'Harare')
```

This is my code that works:

```
result = [i for i in capitals if re.match(".*[aeiouAEIOU]{3}.*$", i)]
print(*result)
```

This is my code that I am trying to use for/in loop:

```
result = []
for i in capitals:
    if i = re.match:
        result.match(".*[aeiouAEIOU]{3}.*$", i)
print(result)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why you're using different conditions in list comprehension and in for loop?

Comment: @OlvinRoght You'd almost have to assume that he didn't write the list comprehension and has no idea how it works. But that couldn't possibly be.

Comment: Why are you calling `match()` on the result?

Comment: @Barmar, it was not just question more attempt to point where actual problem is.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know. But it presumes that he understands what a condition is.

Comment: I did write it myself I was just a bit confused on how to use the for loop.

Comment: If you understand how to use `re.match(".*[aeiouAEIOU]{3}.*$", i)` in the list comprehension, how can you be confused about how to do the same thing in an ordinary `if` statement? Where did `if i == re.match` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop version of the list comprehension would be

```
result = []
for i in capitals:
    if re.match(".*[aeiouAEIOU]{3}.*$", i):
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Comment: Some more explanation would be helpful, rather than just a code dump.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove i equivalent and set the exp logic here..

```
if re.match(".*[aeiouAEIOU]{3}.*$", i):
```

and then, you need to append value in array.

```
result.append(i)
```

That's it.

Enjoy